# How to just float the body left of a page css

Tags: html, css

How do you float the content of my body left of the page via CSS? 
I have tried this in CSS..

```
 .body { 
      float: left;
      }
```

but it doesn't work. Only when I add the method written below does it work..

```
.html, body {
float: left;
}
```

but I do not want to move the whole page, just the body content left. 
What have I missed or shall I say, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the whole page will start displaying in body tag

Comment: Thanks @recursive and zan! forgot to put it in a container..

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have an element with class `body`, this should work.

```css
.body { 
  float: left;
} 

div {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: red;">
  <div style="background-color: yellow;" class="body">
    this is .body
  </div>
  
  text
  text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using your code you are telling your browser to select all tags with with the class "body"

What you are actually trying to do is select the body tag itself so your css should look like the following:

```
body{
CSS CODE HERE
}
```

"#"something{} = tag with the ID of "Something"

"."something{} = tag with the class of "Something"

""something{} = the tag itself "something" (example: body)

---

**EDIT: EXAMPLE OF ID**

HTML Document:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table id="myIDExample">
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Document:

```
body{
float:right;
}

#myIDExample{
padding-left:100px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example for the ID of "something"?

Comment: I added an example of using and ID, these are known as "Selectors" in CSS, that would be the keyword you would want to search for if you googled for help, Selectors will enable you to do a lot, I would suggest mastering them.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Yeah sorry, I keep forgetting the basics haha